# How to calculate$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \sin x dx$ in the most simple way

Tags: calculus

How to calculate$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \sin x dx$ in the most simple way?

I remembered doing this calculation last month and got a result easily without using complex analysis or any big mathematic methods.

However, when I need to do it again today, I lose track of how I did this.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use $\sin x = (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2$.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake the result isn't simple

Comment: which tools are allowed? I do not think that this integral has an elementary simple closed form value ...

Comment: The anti-derivative of your integrand involves the erf function.  Is this for a Calculus I class?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Maybe my memory went wrong. I met this problem in a physics problem and when I say simple (maybe the word was not appropriate) I mean a method that I can easily remember after seeing the proof so that I can remember it in the future without too much calculation in physics application.

Comment: @Bye_World this is used in a physics problem.

Comment: @Mehdi Sorry, maybe my memory went wrong, I assumed there was a simple way, but if there isn't then any approach is good. So far I only learned complex analysis and real analysis, so I prefer methods relating to these.

Comment: Using @JavierBadia's advice, complete the square in the exponent.

Comment: @Lucian: My comment is not as useful as I thought it would be. It would work if the limits were $\pm \infty$ (of course, the integral would be zero), but it doesn't work here because after completing the square, the limits of integration are not simple. It does let you get to the Dawson function quickly, but I thought you could get a closed form solution.

Comment: @JavierBadia: Actually, your suggestion is exactly what the doctor ordered, though apparently not in the way you imagined it.

Answer (score 2):

The question is what you call a "result". But I would suggest the following:

Express the sine function in terms of its Taylor series and switch the sum and the integral (dominated convergence):
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}x^{2k+1}dx$$

The remaining integral can be computed as $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}x^{2k+1}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty 2x(x^2)^ke^{-x^2}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty x^ke^{-x}dx=\frac12\Gamma(k+1)=\frac12 k!.$$
Thus we obtain the series $$\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}k!.$$

And if I have made no mistake then you should be able to use some elementary identities to show that this equals $F(\frac12)$, where $F$ is the [Dawson Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Answer (score 0):

[Knowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}~dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ we deduce that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{\large-\big(x^2+2ax+b^2\big)}~dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{a^2-b^2}\text{erfc }a$ where erfc is the [complementary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). In your case, $a=\dfrac i2$ and $b=0$, hence the result becomes $\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2~\sqrt[\Large4]e}~\text{erfi}\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)$, where erfi represents the [imaginary errof function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). All you need to do is to simply complete the square in the exponent, and employ the very definitions of the functions in question, nothing more.